# click and drag one pixel per keystroke from variable point

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a set of mouse movements assigned to the four arrow keys where a keystroke will click and drag one pixel left, right, up, or down. The starting point will be variable. I have no idea how to accomplish this. I gave it a sort of good faith try before asking, but I really need to ask somebody to show me how to do it.

Thanks,
Ellen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ellen, here we go:

```
#Persistent

^NumPadUp::
Send, {LButton Down}
MouseMove, 0, -1, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel Up
Send, {LButton Up}
Return

^NumPadDown::
Send, {LButton Down}
MouseMove, 0, 1, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel Down
Send, {LButton Up}
Return

^NumPadRight::
Send, {LButton Down}
MouseMove, 1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel to the right
Send, {LButton Up}
Return

^NumPadLeft::
Send, {LButton Down}
MouseMove, -1, 0, 1, R ;Move the mouse one pixel to the left
Send, {LButton Up}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Robert. I had forgotten that second 1.